# How do I add an attribute of type list to each node, with each node have its own unique copy of the attribute

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I need to add an attribute to nodes in a graph of type list.

Each node needs to have its own copy of the attribute.

I need to add this attribute after my graph is created because its not necessary if a function that alters the graph is never called.

I have tried using the nx.set_node_attributes function but this gives every node the attribute I pass to the function by pointer. So every node is pointing to the same single list where as what I want is to give every node is own copy(deepcopy) of the list.

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1, attributelist = [])
G.add_node(2, attributelist = [ 'a', 'b', 6])
G.nodes(data=True)

nx.set_node_attributes(G,[],'TestList')
G.nodes[1]['TestList'].append('Value')
```

I expect the output of the above code to be as follows:

```
NodeDataView({1: {'attributelist': [], 'TestList': ['Value']}, 2: {'attributelist': ['a', 'b', 6], 'TestList': []}})
```

But what I get is:

```
NodeDataView({1: {'attributelist': [], 'TestList': ['Value']}, 2: {'attributelist': ['a', 'b', 6], 'TestList': ['Value']}})
```

I'm fairly sure this is because the `nx.set_node_attributes` has just given each node a pointer to an attribute called `TestList` where as what I need is for every node to have its own copy of `TestList`.

You can see the nodes above have another attribute called `attributelist`. This attribute behaves as I want it to.

So doing an append function to `attributelist` only adds the appended value to the node specified.

```
G.nodes[1]['attributelist'].append('Cat')
G.nodes(data=True)

NodeDataView({1: {'attributelist': ['Cat'], 'TestList': ['Value']}, 2:{'attributelist': ['a', 'b', 6], 'TestList': ['Value']}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing in a single list (value) for all nodes, each node is getting a reference to the same list.

Instead, you can pass in a dictionary to [`set_node_attributes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html) instead of a single list:

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G,{1: [], 2: []},'TestList')
```

Or, more generally:

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G,{ n: [] for n in G.nodes() },'TestList')
```

Comment: I read the example in the documentation for networkx about using a dictionary to do what I wanted but got caught up in the fact that dictionaries are unordered and thinking I needed to keep order information. But that doesn't matter since nodes are the order information I needed.